# Como evitar o NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que tem muitas classes, e muitos arquivos .java, e de um tempo para cá, de vez em quando, esse problema acontece, aleatoriamente. Digamos: Uma classe que eu já usava, está funcionando perfeitamente, do nada se "rebela" e resolve dar esse erro.

Há uma maneira de "prever" e "evitar" esse erro, vendo que isso está aparecendo aleatoriamente no meu projeto?

Eu sei como resolver o problema via código (tanto que existem diversos tutoriais sobre isso), mas esse projeto vai ser usado em uma empresa, e eu não vou ter tempo de vir e corrigir isso toda vez que o sistema resolver se "rebelar".

Comment: Como é que você resolve esse problema via código? Só para ver se eu entendi o que acontece.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError acontece geralmente quando o ClassLoader não consegue ler uma classe informada. Basta dar uma certa atenção aos imports feitos, e bibliotecas de dependencia da aplicação estão corretamente declaradas no classPath, se as classes estiverem todas corretamente na aplicação, este erro dificilmente ocorrerá.

Comment: Math, eu resolvo de uma maneira bem "tosca", não é bem em código, eu copio todo o conteúdo do arquivo que eu desejo "corrigir" (ctrl+a e ctrl+c), apago o arquivo, crio um novo com o mesmo nome e colo tudo de volta lá, ele volta a funcionar normalmente. diegofm, pelo que eu pesquisei, é exatamente o que você falou, mas acontece o seguinte, eu executo o código 1 vez para fazer testes, fecho o programa, quando abre de novo, ele já não funciona mais, é meio raro acontecer, mas ainda assim é chato quando acontece.

Comment: Como você está executando o programa? É a partir de uma IDE, console? A classe que apresenta problema fica dentro de um JAR?

Comment: estou utilizando a IDE netBeans, mas programando os componentes e afins na unha, as janelas são JDialogs e chamadas por botões, todos estão em .java, no momento estou utilizando apenas o "executar" do netbeans para testes, mas vou transferir para JAR quando o programa estiver concluído

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro `NoClassDefFoundError` ocorre quando uma classe existe, mas o `ClassLoader` do Java não consegue carregá-la ou inicializá-la corretamente.

Isso pode ocorrer em várias situações, por exemplo:

- Se você tem um bloco de inicialização estático ou atributo estático que lança alguma exceção, portanto a classe não é carregada.
- Se a classe falha ao carregar uma classe importada por qualquer razão.

Dado que você está executando o código na sua IDE e resolve recriando a classe, o problema pode ser simplesmente que as classes existentes não estão sendo recompiladas na medida em que você faz alterações.

Primeiro, verifique se o NetBeans está configurado para [compilar as classes ao salvar o arquivo](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html#building-compile-on-save).

Se não resolver, use a opção `Clean and Build Project` em todos os projetos envolvidos para forçar a recompilação do projeto.

Se ainda não resolver, verifique suas dependências. Se houver versões diferentes de bibliotecas no `classpath`, isso significa que você pode estar ora carregando uma versão ora outra versão e tendo erros aleatórios.

Comment: Obrigado a ajuda, vou arrumar aqui e ver se continua dando o erro, qualquer coisa posto aqui!

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a documentação oficial da Oracle sobre este erro :

> Lançada se a Java Virtual Machine ou uma instância ClassLoader tenta carregar na definição de uma classe (como parte de uma chamada de método normal ou como parte da criação de uma nova instância usando a nova expressão) e nenhuma definição da classe pôde ser encontrado.
>   A definição de classe procurada existia quando a classe atualmente em execução foi compilada,mas a definição não pode mais ser encontrado.

E caso querer dar uma olhada completa na documentação você pode ver [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html).

Ou seja,isso é causado quando há um arquivo de classe que seu código depende e está presente em tempo de compilação, mas não foi encontrado durante a execução. Olhe por diferenças de seu tempo de construção e o tempo de execução das [classpaths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Por que não usar `try-catch` e colocar o seu código  para sempre que for ocorrer este erro,arrumar ou pelo menos mostrar uma mensagem de erro ?

```
try
{
// Código que irá aparacer caso não ocorra nenhum erro.
}
catch (NoClassDefFoundError e)
{
// Procure olhar no seu código se está instanciando de forma correta.
}
```

Te aconselho a olhar os seguintes links para saber como resolver,por que eles ocorrem e como prevenir este erro :

http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html

http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to_15.html

http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-how-to.html

http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-parent.html

Comment: Valeu a ajuda, vou utilizar sua dica e do utluiz, qualquer coisa posto aqui! valeu!