# Erro java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ao executar aplicação

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

Fiz um programa em java que utiliza o `JDateChooser` para que o usuário escolha a data que deseja. Ele funciona normalmente dentro do Eclipse porém quando exporto o projeto para um `.jar` e tento rodar pelo cdm ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/toedter/calendar/
> JDateChooser
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>     at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
>     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
>     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
>     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544
> )
>     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     ... 7 more
> ```

Classe que utiliza o `JDateChooser`:

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
public class Login implements ActionListener {
    private JFrame ourFrame = new JFrame("Login");

    JTextField user_text = new JTextField();
    JPasswordField pass_text = new JPasswordField();
    static JDateChooser calendario = new JDateChooser();

    JButton yesButton = new JButton("Confirmar");
    JButton noButton = new JButton("Cancelar");

    public Login() {
        ourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ourFrame.setBounds(600, 300, 400, 250);

        Container container = ourFrame.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(null);

        JLabel logo1 = new JLabel("LOGIN CLEARQUEST");
        logo1.setBounds(130, 10, 250, 20);

        JLabel user_label = new JLabel("Usuário:");
        user_label.setBounds(20, 35, 250, 30);

        JLabel pass_label = new JLabel("Senha:");
        pass_label.setBounds(20, 70, 250, 30);

        user_text.setBounds(70, 40, 250, 20);
        pass_text.setBounds(70, 75, 250, 20);

        JLabel logo2 = new JLabel("INSIRA A DATA DO ÚLTIMO RELATÓRIO");
        logo2.setBounds(83, 100, 250, 30);
        calendario.setBounds(83, 130, 210, 25);

        yesButton.setBounds(70, 170, 100, 30);
        yesButton.addActionListener(this);

        noButton.setBounds(210, 170, 100, 30);
        noButton.addActionListener(this);

        container.add(logo1);
        container.add(user_label);
        container.add(pass_label);
        container.add(user_text);
        container.add(pass_text);
        container.add(logo2);
        container.add(calendario);
        container.add(yesButton);
        container.add(noButton);
        ourFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aE) {
        if (aE.getSource() == yesButton) {
            String user = user_text.getText();
            String pass = pass_text.getText();

            RESTInvoker rest = new RESTInvoker(user, pass);
            String json = rest.getDataFromServer();

            try {
                // TODO pega os dados do json (arquivo txt retirado do clearquest) e joga em um Array de testes
                Teste[] teste = null;
                teste = Json.criarJson(teste, json);

                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                Date date = new Date();

                String caminhoTemplate = Variaveis.getCaminhoTemplate(); 
                String caminhoDestino = Variaveis.getCaminhoExcel() + dateFormat.format(date) + ".xls";

                // verificar o caminho
                CriacaoExcel.criandoArquivo(caminhoTemplate, caminhoDestino, teste);

            }

            catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                CaixaDialogo.exibirErro(e.getMessage());
            }

            catch (ParseException e) {
                CaixaDialogo.exibirErro(e.getMessage());
            }

        } else if (aE.getSource() == noButton) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    // envia a data, do relaatório antigo, escolhida pelo usuario
    public static Date enviaData() {
        return calendario.getDate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // para setar o foco nos botões
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                UIManager.put("Button.defaultButtonFollowsFocus", Boolean.TRUE);
                new Login();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Coloquei o Jar do `JCalendar` como mostra a imagem abaixo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

E criei um "Runnable Jar" do meu projeto, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Rodei pelo cmd com o seguinte comando: `java -jar geradorStatus.jar -cp ./lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar`

E apareceu o seguinte erro:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Como está o seu classpath? Que comando você está usando para executar a aplicação? Onde está o JAR do jcalendar e qual é a versão dele?

Comment: Possivel duplicata de [Como evitar o NoClassDefFoundError?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/135995/28595)

Comment: Eu tenho esse jar do Jcalendar e aqui funcionou normalmente, você não incluiu o jar deles como dependencia da sua aplicacao no classpath, esta é a causa do seu erro.

Comment: Eu adicionei ele apenas na `Referenced Libraries`. A versão dele é a 1.3.3 mas eu testei com a 1.4 e também deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Não é ai que tem que adicionar, é ao classpath. E na hora de gerar o jar, precisa informar pra ele considerar as dependencias tambem

Comment: Qual é a linha de comando que você usa no cmd?

Comment: @VictorStafusa é pelo eclipse.

Comment: @Articuno como eu coloco ele pela classpath?

Comment: @Articuno Da pergunta: "*Ele funciona normalmente dentro do Eclipse porém quando exporto o projeto para um .jar e tento rodar pelo cdm ele apresenta o seguinte erro:*" - Ou seja, no eclipse dá certo, e no cmd não.

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu uso o `java -jar geradorStatus.jar`

Comment: @VictorStafusa pelo que entendi, esse "pelo cmd" quer dizer quando ela tenta rodar o jar exportado pelo eclipse. Se nao configurar corretamente a IDE pra incluir as dependencias, vai da problema mesmo se a linha de comando tiver correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de gerar o jar no eclipse, a lib do jcalendar precisa pertencer ao *classpath* do seu projeto. Para isso, adicione-o clicando com o botão direito no projeto e selecione a opção conforme o print:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Na janela que abrir, clique em `Add External JARs` e  inclua o lib do jcalendar.

Depois, clique novamente com o botao direito no projeto, e selecione a opção `Export` para criar o jar. Selecione `Java->Runnable Jar file`.

Na tela seguinte, selecione a classe main da sua aplicação em `Launch Configuration` e logo abaixo marque a opção **Extract required into generated JAR**, para que as dependencias sejam incluidas no seu jar corretamente:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Seguindo esses passos corretamente, o jar será executável sem problemas com as dependências.

Comment: então, foi exatamente isso que eu fiz, e mesmo assim não vai

Comment: @MariTeixeira eu fiz exatamente estes passos usando a sua mesma classe e funcionou, voce deve estar fazendo alguma coisa errada. Refaça todo o procedimento da resposta que irá funcionar.

Comment: fiz novamente e continua com o mesmo erro, não sei se é algo configurado na minha máquina

Comment: @MariTeixeira me faz um favor, siga os passos da primeira imagem da minha resposta e manda um print da janela que abrir, por gentileza.

Comment: os prints estão na minha perguntei, editei e coloquei meu passo a passo lá

Comment: @MariTeixeira se compilar o jar conforme eu expliquei na resposta, você deve executar apenas `java -jar geradorStatus.jar` .Tente recompilar e executar novamente dessa forma.

Comment: deu o mesmo erro

Comment: AH, consegui sem isso sim! Obrigada

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que executar a sua aplicação assim:

```
java -jar geradorStatus.jar -cp ./lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar
```

Comment: rodei e deu o mesmo erro

Comment: @MariTeixeira Em qual pasta o jcalendar-1.4.jar está loclizado? É a mesma do geradorStatus.jar?

Comment: não, ele está em uma pasta "lib" dentro do projeto

Comment: eu coloquei agora dentro da mesma página, e não foi também

Comment: @MariTeixeira Resposta editada. Mas a do Articuno deve ser melhor.